# How to handle a Backbone.Model sync that requires several ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

Let's say I have a Backbone.Model that has the attributes id, a, and b.  When I make a call to the server (let's say it returns json but is not a standard REST server) to fetch the data for id, it returns json that contains the values for a and b.  The json is parsed in my override of the parse() function.  At this point life is good.  Then I do something like the following:

```
myModel.set('a', 'foo');
myModel.set('b', 'blah');
myModel.save();
```

But the server api is not consistent, and I need to call one api endpoint to update 'a' and a different api endpoint to update 'b'. I've overridden the sync() function of my model, would it be correct to call Backbone.sync() twice from my override of the sync() function?  Once for updating a and once for b?  One issue with this is that I can only return the result of one of the Backbone.sync() calls.  Is there are better way to handle this situation?

Comment: Your approach sounds sound. What does this mean though: *I can only return the result of one of the Backbone.sync() calls*. Why wouldn't you be able to merge the results of each back into a single response? Eg when both are done, aggregate the results.

Comment: Well, the documentation for [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) says that it returns a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object. Would those be safe to merge?

Comment: You could probably return a jQuery promise object combining both XHRs (use `jQuery.when(jqXhrA, jqXhrB).promise()`). Admittedly you're not returning a pure `jqXHR` anymore but at least it implements the promise API.

Comment: @SlyMcFly: merge? Not sure what you're getting back, and what callers of `save()` are expecting. Maybe we need more information there. What is the api you hope to attain? Eg call `save()` with a callback, execute the callback with the results from the server? etc...

Comment: @CrescentFresh The api I'm looking for is to have the user call save() and then listen for a custom event (ideally fired from my parse() override) that would indicate pass/fail--where either ajax failing results in a fail event.

Comment: SlyMcFly: perfect information. See @Platinum Azure's comment for a clean approach.

Comment: Which order is preferred for you when you saving `id`, `a` and `b`? Are they dependent? I guess `a` and `b` should somehow reference the `id`? This is important if you need to merge different promises.